# Testing response times using Ganache

Tags: ropsten, ganache, testing, block-interval, ganache-cli

If you want to simulate repsonse time of your smart contract, how realisitc is it to use ganache? I'm thinking that in a live network, ropsten for example, there would be a lot more transactions waiting in the pool compared to the ganache simulated blockchain, which would only contain my transactions. Is it realistic enough by just increasing block time? Especially when measuring the response time from multiple transactions from multiple addresses

Comment: What exactly does `repsonse time of your smart contract` mean? There is no such think as far as I know. Response time is of the miner side, and it is determined by how appealing your transaction is, where the highest gas price in conjunction with the lowest gas is generally the most appealing. These two factors have nothing to do with your contract. The only thing that matters is how you configure each transaction before submitting it for miners to execute it.

Comment: @goodvibration Perhaps saying the response time of the smart contract is incorrect. Rather what I want to measure is how long the transactions take to finish. And if using ganache vs ropsten has a major difference since the mining pool will only contain my transactions in ganache whereas there will be more in a live network. But as you said miners chose transactions based on appeal so yes in the ganache case my transactions will be the most appealing since they're the only ones and in a live network someone else might have more appealing transactions. so i guess that's the difference.

Comment: So I believe that you've pretty much answered your own question `Is it realistic enough by just increasing block time?`, because increasing block time on Ganache is obviously not going to change the fact that your transactions are the most appealing, since they're the only ones there.